# Acumatica open window in new tab

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to open window in new browser tab in Acumatica.
It worked few versions ago, but now if i am trying to open window in new tab it don't.
I am using following code:

```
    public PXAction<ARInvoice> ViewRevBatch;
    [PXButton]
    protected virtual void viewRevBatch()
    {
        if (ConnectedBatches.Current != null)
        {
            Batch batch = ConnectedBatches.Current;
            JournalEntry journalentrygraph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<JournalEntry>();
            journalentrygraph.BatchModule.Current = batch;
            throw new PXRedirectRequiredException(journalentrygraph, true, "Journal Entry");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Nothing is happening? Have you debugged the code and are you sure that the action is being invoked and the exception is really being thrown? Please add the Trace of the Acumatica to the question for more details

Comment: it's showing new window but i needed new tab. found solution

Answer (score 0):

throw new PXRedirectRequiredException(journalentrygraph, false, "Journal Entry") { Mode = PXBaseRedirectException.WindowMode.New };

Comment: the same thing is done when you are using `PXRedirectRequiredException(PXGraph,bool,string)`  constructor. This should not have any difference in workflow.

Comment: I prefer using PXRedirectHelper.TryRedirect(myPxGraph, PXRedirectHelper.WindowMode.New). It also works for PXPopupRedirectException which makes it nice. Same results just makes setting the new window mode cleaner.

Comment: Strange bug seems to happen with my solution. When opening on browser on local computer it works fine. But if opening it on another computer on network it open empty Journal Entry screen.
Problem seems to appear only if opening in new browser tab, but not browser window 
 This is happening in all places. Stuck completely now.
PXRedirectRequiredException(PXGraph,bool,string) just opens new  browser window but not browser tab.
PXPopupRedirectException also open new window.